# Magnific Popup get permalink to post parent

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-post-type, magnific-popup

I set up a Custom Post Type "Women". There are 56 posts that include a portrait and bio. Then, I set up a Gallery page that gets the thumbnail from each post and displays it in the gallery. Clicking a thumbnail opens a modal with the full-size image using Magnific Popup. Where I get stuck is trying to figure out how to add a permalink from the image caption to the Women single page? In this snippet, the permalink links back to the current page and not the post parent. Can I get some direction formatting the titleSrc? Thank you.

```
<ul class="popup-gallery scroll-effect">
            <?php
            $args = array('post_type' => 'women','orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 100);
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                $image = get_field('portrait');
                $post_id = get_field('url', false, false);

                if( !empty($image) ): 
                $url = $image['url'];
                $title = $image['title'];
                $alt = $image['alt'];
                $size = 'medium';
                $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
                $width = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
                $height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];
                ?>

                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">
                        <img class="icon" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/i/icon-image-expand.png">
                        <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?> 
        </ul>

$('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        preload: [0,1]
    },
    image: {
        tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
        titleSrc: function(item) {
         return item.el.attr('title') + ' &bull; <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">Her Story</a>';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where's the PHP code which renders the gallery items HTML?

Comment: Thank you. I just added the PHP to the OP.

Comment: I've just posted an answer. Let me know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PHP part

In the `<a>` tag, set the `href` to the single post permalink, and set `data-mfp-src` to the image URL (`$url`):

```
<li>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-mfp-src="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">...</a>
</li>
```

### JS part

In the `titleSrc` callback, you can then use `item.el.attr('href')` to get the single post permalink:

```
titleSrc: function(item){
  return item.el.attr('title') + ' &bull; <a href="' + item.el.attr('href') + '">Her Story</a>';
}
```

**I put a [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajWpqE/left/) on CodePen**, and for more details about the `data-mfp-src` attribute, refer to the [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#content-types).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. I spent hours on that problem and never came close to this solution that you provided. Thanks again.